# Calculate Long and Lat for a point when Long and Lat of two other points is known

Tags: c#, dictionary, geometry, gis, latitude-longitude

Recently, I have seen an application which loads an image file which is basically a map. Now that application has two reference points( Point1(x,y) and Point2(x,y)) for these points long and lat is defined explicitly, now the application calculates Long and Lat for each point of image. So, I am keen to how to calculates long and lat for remaining points when we know long and lat of two points of a view(which is a rectangle or technically we call Canvas or Render area or viewport)

Comment: It's not that simple, it depends for example on the projection of the map being used.

Comment: If the image covers only small part of earth, finding affine transmation between lon/lat vs x/y should be good enough.  if it's like within 10 km or something.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformation_matrix

Answer (score 0):

I may be mistaken, but isn't that simply applying proportionnality ?

Like you have Point1.x-Point2.x = N, and you know this and increment of M in latitude.

Then for any point Point 3, Point 3 latitude is Point1.Latitude + ((Point1.X - Point3.X)/N)*M